# Selenium - Individually passes, TestSuite didn't

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, frame

I have an automated test about changing frame to a PDF viewer to read the text. I have four tests which basically do the same: Look for a number, letter... and finally test that a word does not exist in the PDF. If I run these test individually, or all frame related test, it works well. But if I run the test suite (which includes like 500 test). One of them systematically fails every time, showing me this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: no such frame

I'm using try/catch, thread/sleep... and all my test are working good, but I cannot figure out why it's always the same test which fails, and why if i run it individually or all the feature, it works. Just wondering if you guys can show me different reasons why this could happen, so I can improve my skills.

Answer (score 2):

Does your test suite take screenshots if the test fails? If it doesn't, I would encourage you to implement a rule for it. (there are numerous examples over the web). A screenshot could shed some light into what is going on.

It sounds like a performance issue though. When you run 1 test, there just isn't a lot of load on the system, and the frame is loaded fast enough for the test to locate it.

However, when you add in the whole suite, tests can sometimes run slower and steps could fail as a result.

It's possible that the failing step is the previous step. If the frame is supposed to load after clicking something, but the click action took place before the link was fully loaded (the link was not actually clicked), then the frame won't be there and the test fails. 
It wouldn't matter how long the failing step waited as the previous step was really the one that failed

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it brings some light overhere. Taking a screenshot could be a great idea, really aprecciate it. I'll try it again and post overhere how it comes. Thanks!!